# Understanding async and await in Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

I'm practicing the fairly new way of calling methods asynchronous but I cannot make it work. In the following code I'm expecting to print out all of the hobbies, but when I run it, nothing happens, no errors it just runs but it doesn't print any of the hobbies.

```
func fetchHobbies() async -> [String] {
    // some asynchronous networking code to get hobbies ...
    let hobbies = ["Cars", "Photography", "Computers"]
    return hobbies
}

func showResults(){
  Task.init{
    let hobbies = await fetchHobbies()
    for hobby in hobbies{
      print("\(hobby)")
    }
  }
}

showResults()
```

I also tried using the `do`, `catch` but no luck.

```
func showResults(){
  Task{
      do {
        let hobbies = await fetchHobbies()
        print(hobbies)
    } catch {
        print("Oops!")
    }
  }
}

showResults()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both ways work (as they should) in playground. How are you running them? I.e. maybe as console app, which quits before it completes?

Comment: Ah, I was using the online editor, `replit`.  I'll try it in a playground.  Thank you for testing it.

Comment: @fs_tigre You can put `RunLoop.main.run()` at the end, to start the runloop on the main thread, similar to how a UI app would. Then other threads have time to do their thing without the whole app shutting down upon completion

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a closer look at `RunLoop.main.run()`,  thanks.

Comment: Just FYI having that floating Task inside of the function kind of defeats the benefits of async await. You lose all control over the task, it creates a leak, etc. also, there is nothing to catch, because you aren’t throwing anything.

Comment: FWIW, `RunLoop.main.run()` is an anachronism (and even when we used that pattern, it was technically not quite right). In Playgrounds we `import PlaygroundSupport` and `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`.